# Use ICommand in Portable Class Library that targets .net 4

Tags: c#, wpf, portable-class-library, icommand

If I create a Portable Class Library that targets .Net 4.0, I don't see any `ICommand` interface available (if PCL targets .Net 4.5 ICommand is in place).

Since ViewModels use `ICommand` extensively, is there a way to share them while still using PCL?

Am I missing something and just don't see ICommand while it should be there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx) link. In Supported features section, it shows that MVVM is not supported for .Net Framework lower than 4.5.

That means if you are creating a PCL targeting .Net Framework 4.0, you cannot use any MVVM feature like ICommand

Answer (score 2):

yes, you have to use .Net 4.5 PCL. it includes  "System.Windows.Input.ICommand" class
Checkout the below link for sample ICommand uses with PCL in .Net 4.5.

[Using Portable Class Library with Model-View-View Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh563947%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, as I mentioned I know that it perfectly works with .net 4.5. Is there a way to make it work while targeting .net 4.0?

Comment: till now, i don't think so there is any way to use this with 4.0 cause it introduced in 4.5 by MS.